# TeamCity fails to build projects using C# 7

Tags: c#, teamcity, c#-7.0

TeamCity is throwing errors when I added new the output variable syntax in our latest code update:

```
if (Enum.TryParse(input, out MyProject.ClassificationType classification))
{
    result.Classification = classification;
}
```

TeamCity threw this error:

`[Csc] MyProject\MyCode.cs(125, 111): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected`

The code builds and runs fine in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

MSBuild on the TeamCity Agent's machine was outdated to using Microsoft Build Tools 2015.

I was able to fix this by downloading and installing the new **Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017** found here:

https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/ -> `Other Tools and Frameworks` -> `Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017` -> `Download`

Or bypass the spam by going here: https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15

Update TeamCity's build step to build using MSBuild 15 or Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: What's the difference between MSBuild 15 and Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: "MSBuild" and "Visual Studio (.sln)" are two different runner types when you're setting up a build step.

Comment: Sorry to be dumb, but I don't know too much about configuring TC. I've been asked to investigate getting C#7 onto it, but am not sure what you mean about different runner types. Please could you explain? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Install the Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 as suggested by Kcoder, 
adjust the build step in Team City afterwards (Example):

[image: Switching to VS 2017 build inside Team City]

In case you use MSBuild as the build step, you can adjust similar settings.